# How can I make a new array from a event emitter ( gives bytes array), where new arrays first element will be '10' and last '13'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have incoming bytes of arrays once a time. It kind of looks like this

[10,12,34,58,62]

[83,33,23,44,13]

[10,12,34,58,62]

[34, 77,54,23,87]

[83,33,23,44,13]

[10,12,34,58,62]

[83,33,23,44,66]

[13]
…continues.

So, it renders each array every time. I needed them to be rendered like

[10,12,34,58,62,83,33,23,44,13]

[10,12,34,58,62,34,77,54,23,87,83,33,23,44,13]

[10,12,34,58,62,83,33,23,44,66,13].

The first element will be 10 and the last 13.
Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide more of your code for context. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: Is that incoming bytes are string or array or JSON.

Comment: @MasoodAlam they are array.

Comment: Check my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// @param {accumulator} is array of array of numbers
// @param {chunk} is the array of numbers
// @return {accumulator} 
const process_bytes = (accumulator, chunk) => {
    if (accumulator && accumulator.length) {
        if (chunk && chunk.length) {
            if (chunk[0] === 10) {
                return [...accumulator, chunk];
            } else {
                return [...accumulator.slice(0, accumulator.length - 1), [...accumulator[accumulator.length - 1], ...chunk]];
            }
        }
    }
    return chunk && chunk.length && [chunk] || [];
};
```

**Assumption**

> The following code follows the provided input data and the expected output in the OP

---

### RUN THE CODE

```js
const process_bytes = (accumulator, chunk) => {
  if (accumulator && accumulator.length) {
    if (chunk && chunk.length) {
      if (chunk[0] === 10) {
        return [...accumulator, chunk];
      } else {
        return [...accumulator.slice(0, accumulator.length - 1), [...accumulator[accumulator.length - 1], ...chunk]];
      }
    }
  }
  return chunk && chunk.length && [chunk] || [];
};

const testData = [
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 13],
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [34, 77, 54, 23, 87],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 13],
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 66]
];

let processed_bytes = [];

testData.forEach(x => {
  processed_bytes = process_bytes(processed_bytes, x);
});
console.log(processed_bytes);
```

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Answer (score 0):

If your incoming bytes is 2d array then try this.

```js
let arr = [
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 13],
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [34, 77, 54, 23, 87],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 13],
  [10, 12, 34, 58, 62],
  [83, 33, 23, 44, 66],
  [13]
]
let openedArr = []
for (let value of arr) {
  openedArr = [...openedArr, ...value]
}

let resultArr = []
let child = []

for (let value of openedArr) {
  child.push(value)
  if (value == 13) {
    resultArr.push(child)
    child = []
  }
}
console.log(resultArr)
```

**Explaination**

1. Make an new array by spreading all incoming array.
2. Create two arrays resultArr and Child Array
3. Push every array elements to Child array
4. If there is 13, then push child array to resultArr, and empty child array.

Comment: Please check your incoming data type.